# How to declare type for functions that receives data from React Child components in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to find the right type for a function I created in a Parent Component which gets data from my Child Component.

I solved it using type: any (obviously) but I could not find the correct type in my occasion. I also tried void, but it returned:

> Type '(dataFromChild: ChildrenReceivedData ) => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)

This is an exemple of a Parent Component extracting data from a Child:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {

    type ChildrenReceivedData = {
        //Data types from child objects
        title: string;
        date: string;
        price: number;
    }

    const handleDataReceive = (dataFromChild: ChildrenReceivedData) => {
        const dataReceived = {
            ...dataFromChild,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <ChildrenComponent onDataReceived={handleDataReceive}/>
    );
}
```

And this is an exemple of the Child component which sends data for the Parent:

```js
type ChildProps = {
    onDataReceived: any;
}
const ChildComponent = (props: ChildProps) => {
    const handleSendData = () => {
        const book = {
            title: 'A Volta dos Que Não Foram',
            price: 39.99,
            date: '1997-06-28'
        }
        
        props.onDataReceived(book);
        
    }
    

    return(
        <h1>Click here to send Book Info</h1>
        <button onClick={handleSendData}>Send!</button>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type needs to match the shape of the function:

```
type ChildProps = {
  onDataReceived: (data: ChildrenReceivedData) => void;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This really should work, maybe you are doing something else wrong?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGEALYAGwBMiA7ZNJYAG5J2AERQwUcALxwA3uTiK4AemViJcGnQDOcbLjhoWHOBABGAKyQZtCpTGAxWSAFxxtMKMC4BzCkrh2cVd3T28-O0UwLz43LgBXEDMkKAoAX0o0CC4POAAFFG4YBlxILiQueBkACgBKaQA%20OUjDbNymFC52Z3UUXn4haThqoIkAMRwQZjZ2N2mObn7BYV76qSb5AICsnPhRvusB4SHNrbOAOkv9idx59gAaFrPFYFm4AFlxJnOoTvZcOrnGAQADKYV8dSeSgyARhShaRBg8SgXGGUMUAB47iVwNkKvBsr0lkJ2FJZB0uj1xAc%20Ms0soGi1aulKFp6Hc8jgwLoZKdFITqcThG4RtSblNjG87otDstRNS4GsmgIIK8WTtctjSnjKkNqtEINy5pLOYbtErmts2vAKd0kCCKvKNDULXythr4GYIBAANYndFbBxOEL4ACCcAAahBWBp-roAIrxegAOQAxxA4GNoCgQPhHs8ttFgLE4ABmACc53L5fzBaUoxDAEZqwB2AC0AAYAGxtgBMAA58AG4WcAwbuecBRIhexql7fcyWiO4JQAojkVxqgGMYy60oMUxGw0GKxi36mCl6MD3I64AAhb1%20gCSXEwEAxykPu73cAxZniMDAqi2QnmeZK2s4DpdL0aQNFB7AAIQfv%20gHZN%20ZwfuhioskAA) Is the playground link.

```
type ChildrenReceivedData = {
    //Data types from child objects
    title: string;
    date: string;
    price: number;
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const handleDataReceive = (dataFromChild: ChildrenReceivedData) => {
        const dataReceived = {
            ...dataFromChild,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <ChildComponent onDataReceived={handleDataReceive}/>
    );
}

type ChildProps = {
    onDataReceived: (dataFromChild: ChildrenReceivedData ) => void;
}
const ChildComponent = (props: ChildProps) => {
    const handleSendData = () => {
        const book = {
            title: 'A Volta dos Que Não Foram',
            price: 39.99,
            date: '1997-06-28'
        }
        
        props.onDataReceived(book);
    }
    

    return(
        <>
            <h1>Click here to send Book Info</h1>
            <button onClick={handleSendData}>Send!</button>
        </>
    );
}
```